# How to use flask-migrate to migrate multi database with different table

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-migrate

I'm using Flask-SQLAlchemy connect to multiple databases.

```
class Car(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    brand = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True)

class Dog(db.Model):
    __bind_key__ = 'database_2'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True)
```

and use command to init migrations

```
flask db init --multidb
```

then I got two databases,'default' and 'database_2'.
When I use command

```
flask db migrate
```

to migrate, only default db schemas been generated to migrate scripts.

And then, when  I use command

```
flask db upgrade
```

'default' and 'database_2' both got car table. Dog table didnt in the migration script.

I need car table in default db and dog table  in database_2.

How can i migrate multi databases with different tables?

Need help,thank you.

Comment: I can't really tell you what's wrong with the little bit of code you showed, but the flask-migrate repo has a complete and working example with multiple databases that you can use as a base to debug the problem: https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/Flask-Migrate/blob/master/tests/app_multidb.py

Comment: Sorry for the little bit of code. I figure it out though this link https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/Flask-Migrate/issues/220 .It turns out, my second database "database_2", didn't import when the migrate command 
 runs.Thanks though.